# Problem with orientation of flowchart

Tags: longtable, block, flow-charts

I have the following flowchart

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}%
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    draw,
    text width=54mm,
    font=\scriptsize,
    %
    grow = south,
    forked edge,  
    s sep = 6mm,  
    l sep = 4mm,  
 fork sep = 2mm,
if level<= 2{text centered}{},
tier/.option = level, % for aligning nodes to levels  
    %
edge = {-{Stealth[length=3pt]}, semithick},
            }
[Feynman Integral
    [Schwinger  Parametrization
%%%% left branch
        [Original Method of Brackets
            [\textbf{Rule 1}: \underline{Expanding Exponential}
             \[{e^{-A} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mfrac{(-1)^n A^n}{\Gamma(1+n)}}\]   
                [\textbf{Rule 2}:\underline{ Expanding Multinomials}
                    {\begin{multline*}
                        (a_1 + a_2 +\dotsm+ a_r)^{\alpha}= \\
                            \sum_{\mathclap{m_1,\dotsc,m_r}} \phi_{m_1,\dotsc,m_r}
                            a_{1}^{m_1}\dotsm a_{r}^{m_r}\\
                                \mfrac{\langle -\alpha+m_1+\dotsm+m_r\rangle}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}
                    \end{multline*}} 
                    [\textbf{Rule 3}: \underline{Introduce Bracket}
                         \[ {\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{l-1}= \langle l\rangle}    \]  
                        [\textbf{Rule 4}: \underline{Eliminate Bracket}\\
                      An expression of the form
                             {\begin{multline*}
                        \sum_{\mathclap{n_1,\dotsc,n_r}}\phi_{1,\dotsc,r}f(n_1,\dotsc.,n_r)\\
                            \langle a_{11}n_{1}+\dotsm+a_{1r}n_{r}+c{1}\rangle\\
                               \cdots \langle a_{s1}n_{1}+\dotsm+a_{sr}n_{r}+c{1}\rangle
                             \end{multline*}}
                        is written as 
                        {\begin{align*}
                        &\mfrac{1}{|detA|}\sum_{n_{s+1}\cdots n_{r}} f(n_{1}^{*},\cdot\cdot,n_{s}^{*},n_{s+1},\cdot\cdot,n_{r})  \\
                        &\cdot\Gamma(-n_{1}^{*})\dotsm\Gamma(-n_{s}^{*})\Gamma(-n_{s+1})\dotsm\Gamma(-n_{r})
                        \end{align*}}
                         provided $det\;A$ is not zero
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [Modified Method of Brackets
            [\textbf{Rule 1}: \underline{Expanding Exponential}
                {\begin{equation*}
        e^{-A} = \oint \mathrm{\frac{dz}{2\pi i}} (A)^z\Gamma(-z)
                \end{equation*}}
                [\textbf{Rule 2}: \underline{Expanding Multinomials}
                    {\begin{multline*}
                (a_1 + a_2 +\dotsm + a_r)^{\alpha} = \\
                \oint\frac{dz_1}{2 \pi i}\dots\oint\frac{dz_r}{2 \pi i} a_{1}^{z_1}...a_{r}^{z_r}\\
                \langle -\alpha+z_1+\dotsm + z_r\rangle\frac{\Gamma(-z_1)\dotsm\Gamma(-z_2)}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}
                    \end{multline*}}
                    [\textbf{Rule 3}: \underline{Introduce Bracket}
                     \[ {\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{l-1}= \langle l\rangle}  \]
                        [\textbf{Rule 4}: \underline{Eliminate Bracket}\\
                      An expression of the form
                             {\begin{multline*}
                        \oint\frac{dz_{1}}{2 \pi i}\cdots \oint\frac{dz_{r}}{2 \pi i}f(z_1,\dotsc,z_r)\\
                            \langle a_{11}z_{1}+\dotsm+a_{1r}z_{r}+c_{1}\rangle\\
                               \cdots \langle a_{s1}z_{1}+\dotsm+a_{sr}z_{r}+c_{r}\rangle
                             \end{multline*}}
                       is written as 
                       {\begin{align*}
                       & \mfrac{1}{|detA|}\prod_{i=s+1}^r\oint\frac{dz_i}{2 \pi i}f(z_{1}^{*},\cdot\cdot,z_{s}^{*},z_{s+1},\cdot\cdot,z_{r})
                   \\  &\cdot  \Gamma(-z_{1}^{*})\dotsm\Gamma(-z_{s}^{*})\Gamma(-z_{s+1})\dotsm\Gamma(-z_{r})
                       \end{align*}}
                        provided $det\;A$ is not zero
                        ]                     
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
%\end{center} % or use `
\end{figure}
```

Now when I try to edit "Rule 1" to "Rule O_1" the orientation of the boxes gets distorted. I want to change all the rule index

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to an MWE (Minimal Working Example} . Also please make code compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you need:

- Provide preamble of document (which is relevant to your code example)
- Remove empty lines from code
- Use curly braces in equation on consistent way. For example:

```
{\[ e^{A} = ... \]}
```

and similar in all occurrence of displayed equations

- "O_1" write as math expression: `$O_1$` or as text `O\_1` (it is not clear, what you like to have here). The later case is considered in the left branch in MWE below. Using it the direction of the tree is not changed.

Considering aforementioned in your code fragment I obtain:

[image]

Above result is obtained with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}%
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    draw,
    text width=54mm,
    font=\scriptsize,
    %
    grow = south,
    forked edge,
    s sep = 6mm,
    l sep = 4mm,
 fork sep = 2mm,
if level<= 2{text centered}{},
tier/.option = level, % for aligning nodes to levels
    %
edge = {-{Stealth[length=3pt]}, semithick},
            }
[Feynman Integral
    [Schwinger  Parametrization
%%%% left branch
        [Original Method of Brackets
            [\textbf{Rule O\_1}: \underline{Expanding Exponential}
             {\[e^{-A} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mfrac{(-1)^n A^n}{\Gamma(1+n)}\]}
                [\textbf{Rule 2}:\underline{ Expanding Multinomials}
                    {\begin{multline*}
                        (a_1 + a_2 +\dotsm+ a_r)^{\alpha}= \\
                            \sum_{\mathclap{m_1,\dotsc,m_r}} \phi_{m_1,\dotsc,m_r}
                            a_{1}^{m_1}\dotsm a_{r}^{m_r}\\
                                \mfrac{\langle -\alpha+m_1+\dotsm+m_r\rangle}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}
                    \end{multline*}}
                    [\textbf{Rule 3}: \underline{Introduce Bracket}
                         {\[ \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{l-1}= \langle l\rangle  \]}
                        [\textbf{Rule 4}: \underline{Eliminate Bracket}\\
                      An expression of the form
                             {\begin{multline*}
                        \sum_{\mathclap{n_1,\dotsc,n_r}}\phi_{1,\dotsc,r}f(n_1,\dotsc.,n_r)\\
                            \langle a_{11}n_{1}+\dotsm+a_{1r}n_{r}+c{1}\rangle\\
                               \cdots \langle a_{s1}n_{1}+\dotsm+a_{sr}n_{r}+c{1}\rangle
                             \end{multline*}}
                        is written as
                        {\begin{align*}
                        &\mfrac{1}{|detA|}\sum_{n_{s+1}\cdots n_{r}} f(n_{1}^{*},\cdot\cdot,n_{s}^{*},n_{s+1},\cdot\cdot,n_{r})  \\
                        &\cdot\Gamma(-n_{1}^{*})\dotsm\Gamma(-n_{s}^{*})\Gamma(-n_{s+1})\dotsm\Gamma(-n_{r})
                        \end{align*}}
                         provided $\det A$ is not zero
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [Modified Method of Brackets
            [\textbf{Rule 1}: \underline{Expanding Exponential}
                {\[e^{-A} = \oint \mathrm{\frac{dz}{2\pi i}} (A)^z\Gamma(-z)\]}
                [\textbf{Rule 2}: \underline{Expanding Multinomials}
                    {\begin{multline*}
                (a_1 + a_2 +\dotsm + a_r)^{\alpha} = \\
                \oint\frac{dz_1}{2 \pi i}\dots\oint\frac{dz_r}{2 \pi i} a_{1}^{z_1}...a_{r}^{z_r}\\
                \langle -\alpha+z_1+\dotsm + z_r\rangle\frac{\Gamma(-z_1)\dotsm\Gamma(-z_2)}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}
                    \end{multline*}}
                    [\textbf{Rule 3}: \underline{Introduce Bracket}
                     {\[\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{l-1}= \langle l\rangle\]}  
                        [\textbf{Rule 4}: \underline{Eliminate Bracket}\\
                      An expression of the form
                             {\begin{multline*}
                        \oint\frac{dz_{1}}{2 \pi i}\cdots \oint\frac{dz_{r}}{2 \pi i}f(z_1,\dotsc,z_r)\\
                            \langle a_{11}z_{1}+\dotsm+a_{1r}z_{r}+c_{1}\rangle\\
                               \cdots \langle a_{s1}z_{1}+\dotsm+a_{sr}z_{r}+c_{r}\rangle
                             \end{multline*}}
                       is written as
                       {\begin{align*}
                       & \mfrac{1}{|detA|}\prod_{i=s+1}^r\oint\frac{dz_i}{2 \pi i} f(z_{1}^{*},\cdot\cdot,z_{s}^{*},z_{s+1},\cdot\cdot,z_{r}) \\ 
                       &\cdot \Gamma(-z_{1}^{*})\dotsm\Gamma(-z_{s}^{*})
                              \Gamma(-z_{s+1})\dotsm\Gamma(-z_{r})
                       \end{align*}}
                        provided $\det A$ is not zero
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```